# php regular expression help finding multiple filenames only not full URL

Tags: php, expression

I am trying to fix a regular expression i have been using in php it finds all find filenames within a sentence / paragraph.  The file names always look like this: 
/this-a-valid-page.php

From help i have received on SOF my old pattern was modified to this which avoids full urls which is the issue i was having, but this pattern only finds one occurance at the beginning of a string, nothing inside the string.

```
/^\/(.*?).php/
```

**I have a live example here:** http://vzio.com/upload/reg_pattern.php

Comment: also : this is a valid filename :  /filename.php {some text after}

Comment: Best typo ever: `finds one occurance at the begging of a string` :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `^` - the carat signifies the beginning of a string/line, which is why it's not matching elsewhere.

If you need to avoid full URLs, you might want to change the `^` to something like `(?:^|\s)` which will match either the beginning of the string or a whitespace character - just remember to strip whitespace from the beginning of your match later on.

Comment: That expression is what i was trying to figure out... my reg skills are horrible. thanks, it works exactly how i wanted  $pattern = "/(?:^|\s)\/(.*?)\.php/";

Answer (score 2):

The last dot in your expression could still cause problems, since it'll match "one anything".   You could match, for example, /somefilename#php  with that pattern. Backslash it to make it a literal period:

```
/\/(.*?)\.php/
```

Also note the `?` to make `.*` **non-greedy** is necessary, and Arda Xi's pattern won't work.  `.*` would race to the end of the string and then backup one character at a time until it can match the `.php`, which certainly isn't what you'd want.

Comment: You were right, it did ignore spaces and try and find the next .php

Answer (score 0):

To find all the occurrences, you'll have to remove the ***start anchor*** and use the `preg_match_all` function instead of `preg_match` :

```
if(preg_match_all('/\/(.*?)\.php/',$input,$matches)) {
 var_dump($matches[1]); // will print all filenames (after / and before .php)
}
```

Also `.` is a meta char. You'll have to escape it as `\.` to match a literal period.